# Filling form in chromium (CEF)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium-embedded

How can I fill a password field on CEF?

I try this:

```
CodeStr := 'document.forms[0].form_password.value="hahaha";';
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(CodeStr, 'mainFrame.GetURL()', 0);
```

but its not work...

The source code is:

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="form_password" value="" size="20" regex="^.{6,}$" class="required" aria-required="true">
</div>
```

Comment: [meta] <div class="field">
<input type="password" name="password" id="form_password" value="" size="20" regex="^.{6,}$" class="required" aria-required="true">
  </div>

Comment: I've never used CEF, but I would think password fields are heavily protected.

Comment: @JerryDodge, no you can write them otherwise tools like LastPass would never work...

Comment: `Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById(''form_password'').value="its not work is not a problem description!"', Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetURL, 0);`

Comment: Tlama: Read of adress00000000

Comment: But its works:

MainFrame := Chromium1.Browser.GetMainFrame;
MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("form_password").value="this_is_a_password"',mainFrame.GetURL(), 0);

THX TLama

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, `MainFrame` property getter calls `GetMainFrame`, so there is no difference between mine and yours code. If you got an AV, you might miss to load a document (but that's what you should always check in production code).

Comment: Thanks.
And what if I want to select something in a listbox?

<div id="mod-oddssetting-1041-container" class="mod" data-mod-type="oddssetting" data-mod-id="1041">




<div id="mod-oddssetting-1041" class="mod-oddssetting mod-oddssetting-oddssetting">
        

    <div id="view-odds-as">
        <label for="select-odds-setting">View odds as:</label>
        <select id="select-odds-setting">
            <option value="fractional" selected="selected">Fractional</option>
            <option value="decimal" >Decimal</option>
        </select>
    </div>

Can I do it to change the value somehow?